# Bash Script to Eject unencrypted USB drive

Tags: macos, bash

I need to forcibly eject any USB drive that is not encrypted.  I have a script already that ejects any USB drive, but I need to modify it to check the encryption status of the disk before ejecting.

Here is the script I have that will automatically eject any USB drive:

```
for disk in $(diskutil list | awk '/disk[1-9]s/{ print $NF }' | grep -v /dev); do
  if [[ $(diskutil info $disk | awk '/Protocol/{ print $2 }') == "USB" ]]; then
    echo "Device $disk is a USB removable disk"
    diskName=$(diskutil info $disk | awk -F"/" '/Mount Point/{ print $NF }')'
    diskutil unmountDisk $diskName
  fi
done
```

So far, the following command will show the encryption status:

```
diskutil apfs list
```

But I am having trouble parsing the output to find the unencrypted disk to eject.  Help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script that works:

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript -e 'display notification "Checking USB" with title "USB Notification"'
for disk in $(diskutil list | awk '/disk[1-9]s/{ print $NF }' | grep -v /dev); do
    if [[ $(diskutil info $disk | awk '/Protocol/{ print $2 }') == "USB" ]]; then
        echo "Device $disk is a USB removable disk"
        diskName=$(diskutil info $disk | awk -F"/" '/Mount Point/{ print $NF }')
        if [[ $(diskutil apfs list ${disk:0:5} | awk '/FileVault/{ print $2 }') == "No" ]]; then
            osascript -e 'display notification "Detected a USB removable disk that is not encrypted, ejecting" with title "USB Notification"'
            echo "Unmounting ${disk:0:5}"
            diskutil unmountDisk ${disk:0:5}
        fi
    fi
done
```